# Including files with ifdef resulting in multiple definitions

Tags: c++, include, linker-errors

I'm trying to understand `ifdef` directive + including files and while it appeared to make sense in my head,  it seems to be not as straight forward as I had thought: I'm getting a "multiple definitions" error.

What I'm trying to do is get the compiler to include certain file depending on if something is defined.

I have `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` both of which have the same function but slightly different logic:

a.cpp

```
int aFunction(int apples){
    return apples * 10;
}
```

b.cpp

```
int aFunction(int apples){
    return apples * 0.1;
}
```

In my main I am trying to do this:

```
#ifdef USE_B
#pragma message "Using b"
#include "b.cpp"
#else
#pragma message "Using a"
#include "a.cpp"
#endif
```

Then in my actual code, call it

```
aFunction(5);
```

I had assumed that the compiler would read those directives and select either `a.cpp` or `b.cpp` and thus the complied source would contain only implementation/instance of `aFunction()`.

But it is doing something I don't quite understand and results in a "multiple definitions" error.

More of the error is below:

```
sketch\b.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `aFunction(int)':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `aFunction(int)'

sketch\a.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

Not quite sure why it is even looking at `a.cpp` when `USB_B` is defined.

I have defined it by going:

```
#define USE_B 1
```

(Side note: Not sure if it matters, but I'm working in the arduino environment).

---

---

### Added thoughts/reasoning

It seems I am getting a bit mixed up in pre-processor, compiling, and linking processes. I admit, it's not something I am too familiar with. (Thanks for cleaning up my tags that reminded me of this)

For me this works and fulfills my goals:

```
#define USE_B 1

#ifdef USE_B
#pragma message "Using b"
int aFunction(int apples){      return apples * 0.1;    } // contents of b.cpp
#else
#pragma message "Using a"
int aFunction(int apples){      return apples * 10;     } // contents of a.cpp
#endif

void main(){
    aFunction(5);
}
```

If I define USE_B, then only the 'b' version of `aFunction` makes it to the generated source (I assume after the preprocessor process) and thus has the effect that only one of the versions of `aFunction` are compiled.

From what I understand, the `#include` directive works as if it was 'copying and pasting' the contents of the included file to where the `#include` directive is. Perhaps I'm wrong here? That's mainly where my confusion is coming from, if `#include` worked by copying the contents of `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` into my main file, shouldn't I get something similar to the above? (which again, works fine for me)

Comment: you're also unconditionally linking in both a.cpp and b.cpp.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish (apart from selecting one version of `aFunction`)?

Comment: Generally, *don't* include source (`.cpp`) files. Use some kind of project-management tool to conditionally build files.

Comment: As a probable reason of your problem, the preprocessor and its macros are a separate language from C++, and as such it doesn't really have statements. Which means you don't terminate macros with a semicolon.

Comment: Whoops. Yea, that ; on define is a typo. Will remove it. I was hoping it would just work, as opposed to using another tool to "select" which version of the function to include. I can use another tool/system do that, it just seemed cumbersome if the compiler to do it for me.

Comment: Ted, I am trying to accomplish exactly that: use one version of `aFunction` that does something OR choose between another version of `aFunction` that does it differently. Trying to do it at the compiler level as opposed to runtime (where one version will never be used). This targets two devices that share 90% of the code and the 10% difference is factored out different within these two 'aFunction's

Comment: If you look at the error message, both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` are used to build your executable. You're not only including the files, you are also creating object files from those source files, and linking with the object files. You need to pick *one* approach (where my recommendation is conditional building and linking rather than including).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, it seems that there's just something I'm not understanding in the whole process. In any case, it also seems the consensus (from responses here and what I can read elsewhere) is that using the pre-processor isn't really the proper way to do what I want and a build system should be used.

Admittedly, it's still a bit strange in my mind, but perhaps one day I'll see it. Since the project is small, I guess I'll just write a simple build script for this.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do instead of `#include`ing the source files, is the same trick Microsoft uses to bind against their two API versions (`xxxA()`, `xxxW()` funxctions):

```
#ifdef USE_B
#pragma message "Using b"
#define aFunction aFunctionB
#else
#pragma message "Using a"
#define aFunction aFunctionA
#endif
```

and in the implementation

a.cpp

```
int aFunctionA(int apples){
    return apples * 10;
}
```

b.cpp

```
int aFunctionB(int apples){
    return apples * 0.1;
}
```

and in your actual code call it

```
aFunction(5);
```

Comment: Would versions `aFunctionA` and `aFunctionB` get complied then? I am trying to limit the amount of space/memory usage in the end. I do like that though as it solves the naming at the very least.

Comment: @mitim This needs to be steered in your build system, not from the code. Anyways, the linker will strip off non selected symbols, but you'll still have to bear the compile time used for both implementaitons, unless you sort this out at the compile phase.